# Objective-C: if (object) Vs. if (object != nil)

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, if-statement

Assuming `object` is a kind of `NSObject`, the following if statements are equivalent, but which style should I use?

```
if (object) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if (object != nil) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wars have been fought over this issue.  I tend to prefer the latter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you say, they're equivalent.  Thus...

> which style should I use?

Whichever one you want.

Comment: I personally think the first is more readable and concise, but again it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent in the sense that they do the same thing. But I would argue that the second statement makes the code more readable. When a person reads the line, they will understand that it means "if object is not pointing to nothing."

Remember Knuth's dictum: a programming language is a way to deliver instructions to a machine in a human-readable form...