# Checking for a nil value

Tags: objective-c, ios, conditional-statements, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [! vs == nil in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782190/vs-nil-in-objective-c)

In Objective C, is there any difference between the following two conditionals?

`NSObject *obj;
if(!obj)
{
...
}`

And:

`NSObject *obj;
if(obj == nil)
{
...
}`

Thanks! Just curious, figure it's a good thing to know.

Comment: No difference. It's C language behavior.

Comment: ...and the [complementary question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366470/objective-c-if-object-vs-if-object-nil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between the two forms.

Answer (score -1):

`!obj` also is valid when `obj=NULL` or `obj=@""` or empty Array etc. You get the point.

i.e. `!obj` is more comprehensive since you seem to be using `NSObject` & not any specific object type.

Comment: `!obj` is *not* true ("valid"?) when `obj` is `@""` or an empty array. Also, `nil` is the conventional way to denote an empty object reference, not `NULL`.

Comment: `!obj` is **not** true when `obj=@""` nor when it's an empty `NSArray` object. `@""` is a pointer to an `NSString` object with a length of `0`. That pointer is never `NULL` (or `nil`) since it's allocated at compile-time.

Comment: want to delete this! I guess thats not possible...